# How to unstack a pandas column according to a certain format?

Tags: python, pandas

My `df` has a column `unnamed` whose first element is

```
'{company=*, location=world, industry=*, segment=*, feature=*, product=*, basekpi=customer_demand}'
```

and second element is `NaN`. I would like to unstack this column into 7 columns `company`, `location`, `industry`, `segment`, `feature`, `product`, and `basekpi`. My `expected_df` is

[image]

Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

```
import pandas as pd
unnamed = ['{company=*, location=world, industry=*, segment=*, feature=*, product=*, basekpi=customer_demand}',
           'NaN']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1], 'unnamed': unnamed})
df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html)

We can use `findall` with regex capture groups to extract key-value pairs from the `unnamed` column

```
pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df['unnamed'].str.findall(r'([^{=,]+)=([^,}]+)')))
```

---

```
  company  location  industry  segment  feature  product          basekpi
0       *     world         *        *        *        *  customer_demand
1     NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN              NaN
```

**Regex details**

- `([^{=,]+)`: first capturing group

  - `[^=,]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[{=,]` one or more times
- `=` : Matches the `=` character literally
- `([^,}]+)` : Second capturing group

  - `[^,]+` : Matches any character not present in the list `[,}]` one or more times

See the online [`regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/RIl6sk/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the unwanted strings and split ,explode then unstack:

```
s = (df['unnamed'].replace({"=":":","{":"","}":""},regex=True)
     .str.split(",").explode().str.split(":"))
u = pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),s.index).set_index(0,append=True)[1].unstack()
out = df.join(u)
```

---

```
print(out)

   id                                            unnamed          basekpi  \
0   0  {company=*, location=world, industry=*, segmen...  customer_demand   
1   1                                                NaN              NaN   

   feature  industry  location  product  segment   NaN company  
0        *         *     world        *        *   NaN       *  
1      NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN  None     NaN
```